# an error on load instagram api

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, instagram-api

i want to connet to instagram api
i have a this pages in my project:

```
\index.html
\js
   app.js
   jquery.js
\css
   style.css
```

my **index.html** :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Photo Search V2</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form">
       <input type="text" id="search" />
    </form>
    <div id="instagram"></div>
    <footer>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

and in app.js:

```
 window.Instagram = {
    /**
     * Store application settings
     */
    config: {},

    BASE_URL: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1',

    init: function( opt ) {
        opt = opt || {};

        this.config.client_id = opt.client_id;
    },

    /**
     * Get a list of popular media.
     */
    popular: function( callback ) {
        var endpoint = this.BASE_URL + '/media/popular?client_id=' + this.config.client_id;
        this.getJSON( endpoint, callback );
    },

    /**
     * Get a list of recently tagged media.
     */
    tagsByName: function( name, callback ) {
        var endpoint = this.BASE_URL + '/tags/' + name + '/media/recent?client_id=' + this.config.client_id;
        this.getJSON( endpoint, callback );

    },

    getJSON: function( url, callback ) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function( response ) {
                if ( typeof callback === 'function' ) callback( response );
            }
        });
    }
};

Instagram.init({
    client_id: 'dbec7d28aef54180b9da9d52061c925b'
});


$( document ).ready(function() {

    Instagram.popular(function( response ) {
        var $instagram = $( '#instagram' );
        for ( var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++ ) {
            imageUrl = response.data[i].images.low_resolution.url;
            $instagram.append( '<img src="' + imageUrl + '" />' );
}
    });

    $( '#form' ).on('submit', function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var tagName = $( '#search' ).val();
        Instagram.tagsByName(tagName, function( response ) {
            var $instagram = $( '#instagram' );
                $instagram.html('');

            for ( var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++ ) {
                imageUrl = response.data[i].images.low_resolution.url;
                $instagram.append( '<img src="' + imageUrl + '" />' );
            }
        });

    });

});
```

-also my clinet id is not that but i put this
when i load **index.html** browser : we have an error :

```
TypeError: response.data is undefined
```

i dont khow where i make a mistake
if it a possibel for you look at it and say me where i make a mistake
tnx a lot

Comment: check whether you are getting any response or not ..

Comment: how?please help me :)

Comment: `callback( response )` replace it with `console.log(response)` if you are getting some response than check the code

Comment: we have  a error : The access_token provided is invalid.

Comment: I solve my problem with use access token